# How can I insert row in table when one field is get updated?

Tags: database

I have requirement like, suppose I have a 'property' table which has 'ListingKey' field and I want to do entry in another table say 'property_history' table whenever 'ListingKey' field is update. How it is possible with mysql ? should I use trigger then how can I use it?

Please Help me,

Thanks,
:Jimit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using trigger you can easily achieve this

following is link for the my sql trigger creation

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html